# Rename file while copying it in build.xml

Tags: java, ant, build

I have a build.xml file and i want to rename a file while copying it in build.xml.

Please find the copy tag below:-

```
<copy file="${basedir}/../../build/ivy-cache/repository/com.abc.sal.pol/pm-remote/jars/pm-api-3.0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" todir="${basedir}/../../drop/deploy/artifact/AgentMgmt/lib"/>
```

I want to rename the file pm-api-3.0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to pm-api.jar as it is copied to ${basedir}/../../drop/deploy/artifact/AgentMgmt/lib" directory . I have tried many things but nothing works. Please help!

Comment: please accept answer which solved your problem or asks for more if not done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use toFile attribute of the copy task.

```
<copy file="${basedir}/../../build/ivy-cache/repository/com.abc.sal.pol/pm-remote/jars/pm-api-3.0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" tofile="${basedir}/../../drop/deploy/artifact/AgentMgmt/lib/pm-api.jar"/>
```

Refer: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html for documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use move task for it (after copying):

```
    <move file="file.orig" tofile="file.moved"/>
```

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html

Comment: Move deletes the source file also. The question asks copying. Refrain from using move unless you want to delete the original file.